# Web scraper + For()

Tags: php, for-loop, web-scraping

I am working on web scraper for images to save some surfing time. Regular scraper for one-page site works great, but my goal website has many web pages, so I need to route my **scraper** multiple times. I tried to use obvious for() loop, but all I get is blank page, no error, nothing. What's the problem?

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i >= 100; $i++) {
    $dom = new domDocument;
    @$dom -> loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.samplewebsite.com/page/'.$i));
    $dom -> preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
      echo "<img src=".$image->getAttribute('src')."><br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: They may be rate limiting your requests. Make sure your server still can access the URL. Also, make sure that the URL is correct and that the url is not being redirected anywhere e.g. to https or to another url.

Comment: I am sure it does not. Moreover, I have tried a loop containing just two iterations and result is the same. Interestingly, if I would copy and paste my code without for loop two times in a row, but with different links, it works.

Comment: Can you just try echo the `file_get_contents` section of the loop to see if it's actually grabbing the page?

Comment: No, it's not grabbing if using the loop. Without the loop it's all good.

Comment: Oh gosh, bug was in the $i >= 100, it should be $i <= 100. How could we unsee that? Thanks for the conversation, by the way!

Comment: Haha, I didn't notice that either :P